# How do I create a new project in Neos CMS?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, composer-php, neoscms

I recently turned a computer into a Ubuntu server. I have installed all dependencies following the article below http://neos.readthedocs.io/en/stable/GettingStarted/Installation.html

My version of Ubuntu (or Apache) did not have a "htdocs" folder like the previous article suggested, so I created a folder called newsletter in var/www/html per this article https://askubuntu.com/questions/683953/where-is-apache-web-root-directory-on-ubuntu

Then I try to complete step 2 of "Fundamental Instruction" by using the following code

```
cd /your/htdocs/
php /path/to/composer.phar create-project neos/neos-base-distribution Neos
```

but it does not work.

Instead of inputting "cd /your/htdocs" I navigate to /var/www/html
I am getting "Could not open input file: /path/to/composer.phar"

I believe I already have composer installed, so I don't really want to have to go through https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04

Should I change "/path/to/composer.phar"? Has the location changed?

Answer (score 0):

It look like your composer is not in the given path `/path/to/composer.phar`

composer is not included in a bare bone Ubuntu, so you should have to follow the setup. If you want to test Neos, check https://bitnami.com/stack/neos

> Should I change "/path/to/composer.phar"? Has the location changed?

This path is just an example.